# How to use javascript in AppleScript to return a list of users in a chat room

Tags: javascript, html, macos, applescript

Trying to return a list of users in a chat room. The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="users-list" style="height: 475px; display: block;">
```

That expands to this:

```
<div class="text" data-nick style="float:right">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user1">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user2">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user3">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user4">...</div>
```

Using the javascript console in Google Chrome, I do:

```
document.body.querySelector("div.users-list")
```

Which returns the original unexpanded HTML:

```
<div class="users-list" style="height: 475px; display: block;">
```

There is a drop down arrow to expand this in the javascript console which returns the user list:

```
<div class="text" data-nick style="float:right">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user1">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user2">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user3">...</div>
<div class="text" data-nick="user4">...</div>
```

What I'd like to do is write the list of users to a text file. I tried doing this in Bash with `osascript`:

```
osascript -e \
'tell application "Google_Chrome"
    tell window 1
        tell active tab
            execute javascript "document.body.querySelector(\"div.users-list\")"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell'
```

But when I run this in my terminal it returns a blank line. When I run this as AppleScript in Script Editor, it only returns `{}`

How can use the javascript `"document.body.querySelector(\"div.users-list\")"` in AppleScript / osascript to return the same expanded user list that is returned using the javascript console in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) doesn't return a string (HTML or otherwise); it returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) object. Chrome renders this in the console with text, but AppleScript/osascript might render it differently, or not at all.

You might want to consider using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), which returns the HTML of the contents as a string:

```
execute javascript "document.body.querySelector(\"div.users-list\").innerHTML"
```

---

Since there is an appropriate rendering for an array of strings, we can map each of the children of the `div.users-list` to some string, using the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
execute javascript "[...document.querySelector(\"div.users-list\").children].map(x => x.outerHTML)"
```

(This also makes use of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

---

Of course, you can also extract information from each child div within map and return that information. The following uses [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#JavaScript_access) to read HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
execute javascript "[...document.querySelector(\"div.users-list\").children].map(x => x.dataset.nick)"
```

and will output:

> user1, user2, user3, user4

Comment: Using `"document.body.querySelector(\"div.users-list\").innerHTML"` does produce output now. However, it seems to be one long string. Is there a way you know of to keep the output in a list form?

Comment: @I0_ol Can you output a Javascript array? What happens if you do `execute javascript "[\"a\",\"b\"]"`? If yes, then I would leverage the Javascript [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function somehow, to map each node into a string.

Comment: The output from `execute javascript "[\"a\",\"b\"]"` is `a, b`

Comment: @I0_ol Updated.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!